# Mat-Autocomplete selected option should be highlighted and be the top drop-down choice displayed; I should be able to scroll up or down in listing

Tags: angular

I am able to display the selected option as first one on immediate mat-autocomplete panel open, by using the following code

```
    let selectedOption = this.dropdown.autocomplete.panel.nativeElement.querySelector('.mat-active');
    if (selectedOption) {
    const scrollTopValue = selectedOption.offsetTop -      
        this.dropdown.autocomplete.panel.nativeElement.offsetTop;
    this.dropdown.autocomplete.panel.nativeElement.scrollTop = scrollTopValue;

    }
```

But when using down arrow, instead of it moving to next option after selected option, it moves to first option in the list. When using up-arrow, instated of it moving to previous option, it moves to last option in the list.

I tried with the following code to override the default behavior of mat-active, but not achieve the required functionality

```
onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) { 
  const options= this.dropdown.autocomplete.panel.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.mat-option');
    const currentIndex = Array.from(options).findIndex((option: HTMLElement) =>
    option.classList.contains('mat-active'));
    options.forEach(a=>a.classList.remove('mat-selected','mat-active'));
    if (event.key === 'ArrowDown') {
      event.preventDefault();
      const nextIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % options.length;
      options[currentIndex].classList.remove('mat-active');
      options[nextIndex].classList.add('mat-selected','mat-active');
      options[nextIndex].scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'nearest' });
    } else if (event.key === 'ArrowUp') {
      event.preventDefault();
      const previousIndex = (currentIndex - 1) % options.length;
      options[currentIndex].classList.remove('mat-active');
      options[previousIndex].classList.add('mat-selected','mat-active');
     options[previousIndex].scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'nearest' });
    } 
}
```

Please suggest me the way, how to achieve the above functionality.